# Move file from share file convert it to .txt then remove it

Tags: excel, windows, powershell

I am taking an excel report moving it from a share drive with a partial file name changing it to an txt file then renaming it than removing the one from citrix. Problem is the file is not changing to a txt or renaming and also not removing itself from citrix

I am very new to powershell could anybody offer insight?

```
Move-Item -Path 'S:\test\test*.xls'  -destination c:\test

$files = Get-ChildItem c:\test\test*.xls 

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files) {
 Write "Loading File '$($file.Name)'..."
 $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
 $NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".txt")
 $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 42)   # xlUnicodeText
}

# cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Rename-Item -Path "C:\test\test*.txt" -NewName "test1.txt"
Remove-Item -Path C:\test\test*.txt `
```

Comment: "I am having trouble" - always helps to explain exactly what your trouble looks like

Comment: this `\\c\test` is not a valid path. is part of it missing?

Comment: I presume you mean `C:\test` not `//c/test`? Also we're going to need the actual error or examples of where it is failing.

Comment: I am taking an excel report moving it from a share drive with a partial file name changing it to an txt file then renaming it than removing the one from citrix.
Problem is the file is not changing to a txt or renaming and also not removing itself from citrix